# Why does JavaScript return false when comparing a variable with two true statements?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comparison, operators

In the following javascript code,

```
var a = 5;
console.log(5 <= a >= 6);
```

False is printed to the console.
However, true is printed for the statements 5 <= a and a >= 6. Is it something to do with the double comparisons?

Thanks!

Comment: `a >= 6` is `false`.

Comment: I think the problem is your understanding of what the two comparisons actually are... `((5 <= a) >= 6)`

Comment: Depends on the precedence and associativity of the operators you've used.

Answer (score 4):

When you test if `5` is less than or equal to `5` you get `true`

When you test if `true` is greater than or equal to `6` you get `false`

(You would also get `false` if you tested to see if `5` was greater than or equal to `6`)

If you want to do multiple tests with the same value, then you need to actually test that value multiple times.

e.g.

```
if (5 <= 6 && 5 <= 6)
```

or

```
if (5 <= 6 || 5 >= 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write things like this, you seem to be testing whether:

```
(5 <= a) >= 6
```

`"5 <= a"` evaluates to true, but the statement `"true >= 6"` evaluates to `false`.